# LARAVEL: I am only getting one item from my table when there are multiple items. How would I get all of them and output them?

Tags: php, database, laravel, session

I am using a session to create a basic cart. In the session there are multiple IDs ranging from 1-3.

When I output the data using foreach it only outputs the first item from the table. I would like all the related items to appear. How would I go about doing that?

**Here is my index function from my controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    session_start();
    $cartData = implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);
    $cartProducts = Product::where('id',$cartData)->get();
    return view('basket',['cartProducts'=>$cartProducts ],['cartData' =>$cartData] );
}
```

**This is my output on the cart page:**

```
  @foreach($cartProducts as $cartProduct)


         <p>{{$cartProduct->name}}</p>
         <p>{{$cartProduct->size}}</p>
         <p>{{$cartProduct->price}}</p>

  @endforeach
```

**And for testing purposes this is my dump and die of the $cartData:**

```
"1,1,3"
```

**And finally this out the actual output:**

```
Original

small

8
```

Comment: **do not use `$_SESSION` and `session_start`, you have `Session` facade/helper to do so...** You are not using Laravel as you should, be careful as you are going to get bad habits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You're passing in a string of IDs instead of an array
2. `where` only looks for a single value.

So the query is actually becoming `where id = '1,1,3'`, which may only match the id of `1`. To fix it, pass in the actual array, and use `whereIn`:

```
Product::whereIn('id', $_SESSION['cart'])->get();
```

This changes the query to `where id IN (1,1,3)`.

Comment: Thank you! that has fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You are just using where, which is not helpful on what you are trying to achieve.

You should rather be using whereIn (equivalent to wherein() in sql) without imploding (use array directly).

```
->whereIn('id', $cartData)
```

This should solve your problem.